# Autowired in Lambda AWS with Java Spring boot not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, aws-lambda

I have several lambda functions in Java and all of them have worked correctly, except this project which is similar to the others. When it tries to access BrowardService it returns null and doesn't catch the injection, here is the code:

[image]

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Answer (score 0):

Here the code:

```
@Slf4j
@SpringBootApplication
public class LambdaBrowardApplication {

    @Autowired
    BrowardService browardService;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FunctionalSpringApplication.run(LambdaBrowardApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public String handleRequest(Map<String,Object> input) {
        log.info("-----> INPUT: " + input);
        try{
            ApplicantDto applicantDto = ApplicantDto.builder()
                    .appId((Integer) input.get("appId"))
                    .reportId((Integer) input.get("reportId"))
                    .firstName((String) input.get("firstName"))
                    .lastName((String) input.get("lastName"))
                    .middleName((String) input.get("middleName"))
                    .dob((String) input.get("dob"))
                    .build();
            log.info("-----> INPUT: " + applicantDto);
            if (browardService == null) log.info("--------> BROWARD is null");
            BrowardResponseDto browardResponseDto = browardService.runBroward(applicantDto);
            return browardResponseDto == null ? null : new Gson().toJson(browardResponseDto);
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            log.error("-------> ERROR: " + e.getCause());
            return "There was a problem parsing the request.";
        }
    }
}
```